# Editar é melhor que fechar. Mas quando?

Tags: debate

O caso em questão ocorreu nesta pergunta:

[Como colocar o valor de uma variável PHP dentro de um input?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242426/5878)

A pergunta (original) é claramente insuficientemente clara e todas as respostas foram dadas baseadas em alguma especulação. Nos [comentários de uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242430/5878), o autor esclareceu o que realmente estava tentando fazer e percebi que não condiz com a pergunta dele.

Na pergunta, tudo indica, devido a ausência de detalhes, que os códigos estão no mesmo arquivo e que o problema é apenas a ordem dos mesmos, utilizando uma variável que ainda não foi definida - todas as respostas foram dadas nessa hipótese. Nos comentários supracitados o autor esclarece que os códigos estão em arquivos separados, demonstrando que o problema real é a compreensão de como é executada uma requisição POST a partir de um formulário - e não a ordem dos códigos, como especulado.

Eu [editei a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/242426/4) colocando realmente o problema do autor de forma a poder ser solucionado, porém isso iria descaracterizar as respostas que foram dadas por especulação. Acabei por desfazendo a edição e mantendo a pergunta original, nada clara.

A questão é: neste caso o ideal seria editar, de fato, a pergunta, de forma a atender o real problema do autor e excluir as respostas dadas ou aceitar o fato de que a pergunta estava mal formulada, gerou respostas baseadas em especulações e orientar o autor a abrir uma nova pergunta? Neste segundo caso, a pergunta deveria ser fechada como insuficientemente clara? Ao meu ver, é o correto.

Comment: sou iniciante no stackoverflow e ainda tenho algumas dúvidas sobre como seria a melhor forma de perguntar. Outra questão, é que também sou iniciante na programação e não conheço bem as melhores formas de expor minha dúvida. Obrigado pelas ponderações , já é uma boa base para seguir.

Comment: Eu diria que o correto, nesse caso, seria abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado [E foi feito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242452/n%c3%a3o-consigo-retornar-para-a-input-o-valor-de-um-post-em-php). Mas na minha opinião ta pior que a outra. kk

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado e o que fazer com uma pergunta que não pergunta o que quer e não responde o que precisa?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas pelo menos pergunta algo minimamente aceitável sobre programação?

Comment: @Francisco tá realmente complicado de entender essa segunda pergunta...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Complicado. Na minha opinião essa preocupação faz mais sentido em casos em que a edição **altera** o sentido da pergunta. Nessas situações a mudança de sentido invalida todas as respostas dadas (em alguns casos até com resposta aceita), e torna a pergunta completamente inútil pra quem chega, que não tem seu problema resolvido, já que as soluções não servem.

Mas agora a pergunta estava apenas confusa. Não é incomum que o real sentido de uma pergunta só seja descoberto depois de uma série de comentários. Acontece... E em casos assim o melhor a ser feito é atualizar a pergunta. Se de fato os códigos estão em arquivos separados, isso é essencial à pergunta, e merece estar nela. Nada está sendo alterado, apenas esclarecido.

O que torna esse caso mais complicado é o número de respostas já existentes, antes da confusão inicial ser dissipada. Não é culpa de quem responde compreender errado o sentido de uma pergunta que não está clara, mas ainda assim, ao meu ver, a pergunta merece ser atualizada. Requer muito menos manutenção e esforço do que abrir uma nova, explicar tudo de novo, e fazer campanha pelo fechamento/remoção da original - já que pode não ser claro para os outros votantes *por que* ela está sendo fechada/removida.

Mesmo sendo um caso mais difícil, eu ainda acho que a edição é o caminho menos confuso.

Comment: Concordo contigo. Este nem seria o caso de alterar o sentido da pergunta pois esta nem tinha um propriamente dito. A minha preocupação mesmo foi com as respostas, pois me parecia injusto, mas ao mesmo tempo é um risco que corre ao responder uma pergunta não tão clara. É até meio difícil definir uma fronteira nesse contexto.

Answer (score 5):

Vou responder algo que se baseia em minha *opinião*, se a pergunta demostra qualquer possibilidade de ser um pouco ambígua ou não clara ou até mesmo ampla, não arrisquem respostas, isso eu digo claramente para quem respondeu.

Tem muito caça-votos, sim é uma critica, isso é saudável desde colocando em foco que o principal intuito do site seja ajudar e tenha o minimo de conhecimento para abordar todos pontos possíveis da pergunta.

Mas todos os dias vejo respostas prematuras em perguntas que já tem até 4 votos de fechamento, o erro pra mim é de quem responde algo assim que não esta claro ou até amplo, e digo uma coisa não são poucos que fazem isto.

As únicas exceções que acho válido responder algo que esteja amplo, não claro ou ambíguo é quando:

- Você tiver a certeza que ao responder vai dar uma resposta muito completa que vai cobrir todos os pontos, tem usuários no site (geralmente veteranos) que já tem essa pratica e geralmente fazem ótimas respostas.
- Quando você conversou com o autor da pergunta e tem certeza que entendeu perfeitamente o sentido da pergunta.

Ao meu ver o erro foi totalmente de quem respondeu prematuramente e a pergunta deveria ser editada sim para ficar mais clara.

Infelizmente eu já tentei conversar uma duzia de usuários com este tipo de atitude, tentei orientar, a maioria leva a mal ou simplesmente ignoram, pensam estar ajudando, outros pensam que isto é algum tipo de fórum de suporte técnico e que o importante é tentar ajudar mesmo que não tenham entendido a pergunta, eu já recebi desculpas dos mais tipos absurdos e até já fui insultado por uma meia-duzia que simplesmente entendem orientações como ataque pessoal.

---

> Editar é melhor que fechar. Mas quando?

*(opinião pessoal)* Edite se a pergunta não for clara mesmo, ou seja for mais que simplesmente ambígua, infelizmente quem foi precipitado foi quem respondeu.

Agora se a pergunta for o tipo pergunta *camaleão*, que já foi comentado no Meta, então o correto seria não editar e se alguém editou então o ideal seria reverter, acontece as vezes do autor mudar completamente o sentido da pergunta, nesse caso vai depender muito mesmo, só olhando pergunta a pergunta, não existe um padrão.

Penso eu que o tipo de pergunta que geralmente é fechado mas que tem mais chances de ser reaberta é o **Não está claro** e as vezes o **Ampla demais**, mas é caso a caso mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Vim aqui compartilhar um caso recente, ainda está fresco.

Não cheguei a fazer, de fato, a edição. Mas atuei na identificação do problema.

A pergunta em questão é [Desafio de possibilidade em c,c++ ou matlab](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243061/64969). Passei por mais ou menos meia hora de troca de comentários (11 comentários para essa extração de informação), para então poder elaborar uma resposta em mais ou menos outra meia hora. Aí então o AP dá um *rage quit*!

Fiquei possesso de raiva, xinguei muito no chat. Para então descobrir que o mesmo AP havia feito uma outra pergunta a uns 10 dias atrás e nem feedback ao autor da resposta (o Maniero, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239577/64969) ele deu!

Nesse caso, no caso desse AP, estou inclinado a não mais tentar procurar salvar suas possíveis futuras questões, devido a esse comportamento. Como se o esforço do Maniero não fosse digno! Nesse meu caso específico, creio que marcarei para fechar as questões futuras, não mais tentarei salvar. Para mim, esse AP alcançou o limiar do não valer a pena salvar.

---

Novo capítulo, AP interagiu com uma das questões. Até minha última olhada, ele ainda não tinha selecionada a do Maniero nem dado feedback do porquê achou ruim.

Enfim, desbaixou do meu conceito, talvez eu possa voltar a ter fé na humanidade depois dessa. Esperar mais um pouco para interagir na pergunta que o Maniero respondeu para ver o que tem nela que não satisfez o AP.